# Converting Orthogonal Camera to Perspective OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm having some troubles converting a orthogonal camera to a perspective one, using OpenGL.
I currently have my orthogonal camera following a middle point of two objects, using:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0,_winWidth,0,_winHeight,150,-150);
glTranslated(-_middlePoint[0]+_winWidth/2, -_middlePoint[1]+_winHeight/2, 0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

The above code works perfectly, now i'm trying to use it like this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45.0, _winWidth/_winHeight, 1.0, 1000.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0, 0, 800, _middlePoint[0], _middlePoint[1], 50, 0, 0, 1);
glLoadIdentity();
```

And I simply get a black screen. Any thoughts? I've tried changing the up vector from 0,0,1 to 0,1,0 and it stays the same.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have code working using `glOrtho` already, you can normally switch to a perspective projection by simply changing that to `glFrustum`. If you're writing new code, `gluPerspective` and `gluLookat` may be easier, but for code that already works using an orthographic projection, it's easy to switch to perspective by just calling `glFrustum` with the same parameters.

Comment: How could I apply that to this particular example?

Comment: @pirezas: Like I said, just change `glOrtho` to `glFrustum`, leave the code completely unchanged otherwise, and re-compile. Unless you've done something strange elsewhere, your projection will change from orthographic to perspective with no other changes.

Comment: Well I tried that but it still doesn't work :/ Thanks for the suggestion though.